# Raspberry Pi Keyboard and Mouse with KVM switch not working

Tags: pi-4, keyboard, debian, mouse

I want to connect multiple Raspberry Pis with a single display, mouse and keyboard through a KVM switch and have the following equipment:

Raspberry Pi x 2

RP Keyboard and mouse x 1

Display x 1

KVM Switch x1

OS -  Debian

The display for  RPis, through the KVM switch works fine. However, the mouse and keyboard do not work when connected with the switch. They do work when connected directly with the Pis. I have tried several things from the blogs such as enable virtualisation or disable `logitech` but nothing worked.

Please help!

Comment: I just found a Logitech Pebble 2 Combo, Wireless Keyboard and Mouse, that has new bolt usb wireless tx/rx that connects to one RPi and can connect to two more computers using bluetooth through keyboard keys and mouse switch (the mouse is kind of flat).

Comment: the KVM switch emulates a keyboard and a mouse for each computer at all times ... either the RPi does not have the right drivers, or the KVM switch does not understand your mouse and keyboard

Comment: Any pointers, from where I can drivers